# How can I make two applications on the same PC talk to each other via UDP on the same port via Broadcast

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, udpclient

I'm trying to build a chat client and server that run on the same PC and communicate via UDP Broadcast (or loopback) on the same port. I am able to get the chat client to send the chat server a message, but when I try and reply, the client doesn't get the reply.

I think the crux of the issue is that I don't get how to work around VisualStudio preventing you from running two listeners on the same socket. I tried to work around this as others hinted toward online by listening for broadcast messages on one, and listening for IPAdress.Any on the other. I tried mixing around IP addresses and Loopback, but it always seems to fail.

## Chat Server:

```
    int port = 10500;
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(port);
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
    IPEndPoint sendipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.255"), port);

...

//Main
   udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;

...

//Send
    udpClient.Send(outgoingData, outgoingData.Length, sendipep);

...

//Receive
        
        while(true) {
            data = udpClient.Receive(ref ipep);
```

## Chat Client:

```
    private int port = 10500;
    UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient("192.168.0.255", port);
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.255"), port);

...

//Main
    udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;

...

//Send
    udpClient.Send(outgoingData, outgoingData.Length);

...

//Receive
    byte[] incomingData = udpClient.Receive(ref ipep);
```

I expect the client to receive the incoming message, but it doesn't seem to ever get it. Thanks for reading!

Comment: What is the rest of your code?  Are you checking to see if there's data to be read before reading from the receive buffer?  Also, I'm pretty sure you can use local host for the `IPAdress` if you are running on the same machine.  I'm not 100% sure on that though.

Comment: Just looked back through some old code.  I can confirm you can use local host `127.0.0.1` for your `IPAdress`.

Comment: @JoshuaStevens the .Receive method actually blocks until there is data to be read. I did try IPAddress.Loopback and plugging in 127.0.0.1, neither seemed to work. I'm not sure why, but VisualStudio seems to complain if you have two applications' UdpClients listening on the same sock. I ended up changing over to TcpClients and it works fine with much less headache. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, past what I posted all my old networking stuff is in c++.  Besides working with `HTTPClient` I haven't done any networking in c#.  I can tell you though that while it's not going to solve your problem, `127.0.0.1` is probably what you are going to want to use.  I'm not 100% sure but I believe having your computer's local address will cause you issues if it ever were to change.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, `Receive` is blocking but just not getting anything?